# putty on windows using AF_UNIX

Tags: networking, network-programming, putty, windows

I have recently downloaded source code for putty for windows client. It is using AF_UNIX 
address family. AFAIK AF_UNIX socket family is not present in windows. Then how it is working
here ? I am working on porting a *nix project to windows which has AF_UNIX socket family.

Thanks
Arpit

Comment: And you know... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3872558/af-unix-in-windows/3872595#3872595

Answer (score 0):

The AF_UNIX define is still there in Windows, from when the BSD socket interface was ported to Windows by Microsoft, but there is no actual support for AF_UNIX in Windows.

Putty in Windows can not support AF_UNIX. Maybe the Linux port of Putty can, possibly.

If you really, really want to use AF_UNIX in Windows, try to develop in [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com) which has a user space implementation of AF_UNIX.