# What are the available options for interprocess communication in broadcast and consume model

Tags: python-3.x, ipc

Consider my main script as a loop that is constantly broadcasting various events happening. For example:

```
FileChange: File at address XXX has changed.
FileDeleted: File at address XXX has been deleted.
ScreenSaver: Screen saver named YYY got activated.
...
```

What I intend to do is to have other apps that I would add now (and later on), listen to what main app is broadcasting and if it is related to it (say a script for handling `FileChange` events), they get the message and do their own processing.

What are my options for achieving this model of interprocess communication?

Comment: Pub/sub with Redis maybe? https://redis.io/topics/pubsub

Comment: Redis was very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you structure your application using threads you could use the python `queue` library for that https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html - it is a class supporting multiple producers and consumers. I often use that for structuring my applications for propagating events among different listeners.

If you want to separate different processes you could choose something from [Recommended Python publish/subscribe/dispatch module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115844/recommended-python-publish-subscribe-dispatch-module#)

In your case a [unix domain socket](https://pymotw.com/2/socket/uds.html) could be a simple possibility without using difficult frameworks (you could even write shell programs for accessing that). Meanwhile it seems to work under Windows as well ([AF_UNIX equivalent for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029174/af-unix-equivalent-for-windows)). Your service could publish events with a simple ASCII protocol like `<EVENT>:<PATH>` on the socket.